# read cmd_vel commands from a text file

Tags: ros, gazebo, navigation, turtlebot, rostopic--pub

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

Please, note that I'm a beginner in ROS. I'm using the turtlebot robot in gazebo. I know how to send a velocity command from the terminal, e.g., move forward 1m/s. But, What I would like is to send a sequence of consecutive commands. Would it be possible to read them from a text file, for example?

I hope my questions makes sense,
Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55597/read-cmd_vel-commands-from-a-text-file/) by [Evis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4178/evis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2013-02-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't worked with turtlebot or gazebo but the answer is almost certainly yes. The basic idea is that you want to read your text file line by line as you normally would in python/c++. Split each line into different values you want then publish these programmatically as Twist messages as explained in this tutorial http://pharos.ece.utexas.edu/wiki/index.php/Writing_A_Simple_Node_that_Moves_the_iRobot_Create_Robot#Create_the_Program. You should do all of this work inside a node which you start after your robot has started. Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [Tadhg Fitzgerald](https://answers.ros.org/users/4009/tadhg-fitzgerald/) with karma: 98 on 2013-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Evis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4178/evis/) on 2013-02-19**:
Thanks. I got the idea. That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can just use the rostopic tools for that.
Create a yaml text file with contents in the same format that `rostopic echo cmd_vel` would give you (or in general for any other message) and pipe that file into rostopic, e.g.:

```
cat my_cmds.txt | rostopic echo /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist
```

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check the answer here:
http://answers.ros.org/question/51857/import-file-for-executing-cmd_vel/

---

Originally posted by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) with karma: 229 on 2013-03-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1